# Save javascript logs to my server

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, debugging, logging

Hello some of my users seem to have problems with a certain jquery library I am using on my mobile App.

I am unable to recreate to issue on my own, furthermore the App is integrated into a native App, which only allowes access to their javascript logs via Android adb. My App doesn't work with a normal browser, so I basically have no way on getting my hands on the produced error logs of the clients with the problem.

My question is if there is a way I can access the produced Javascript Log with Javascript / JQuery Code and send it to my server, or redirect the produce logs to a variable instead of the javascript console?